# Why does this PD 3.0 charger no longer switch to 20V 3A (60W) PD 3.0 after charging the smartphone at 9V 3A (18W)?

Tags: laptop, usb-c, charger, usb-power-delivery

This [Amazon Basics USB C charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087MFDTL4) was able to use 20V 3A (60W) PD 3.0 to charge a laptop Lenovo Flex 5.

However, after charging the smartphone through the 20V 3A (60W) port at 9V 3A (18W), it "intelligently" changed the charging voltage to fit the smart phone, but stopped switching to the 20V 3A (60W) PD 3.0 charging mode when connected to the laptop.

The charging ports, the cable were both working and the laptop were able to identify the low voltage at the charging port.

Was there a way to reset the charger so that the 20V 3A (60W) PD 3.0 mode could be used to charge the laptop again?

[image: Image of the Amazon Basics USB C charger.]

Comment: I think there is a language issue here; before the charger stopped working as expected, it was charging the laptop of 50w? And now it is stuck at 20w (and not 20V)?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It was using the pd3 protocol and charging at 20V 3A (60W). However, after charging the smartphone from the main port, both ports was using the "fast charging" voltage (9V 3A), but the port was no longer able to switch to 20V 3A(60W) with pd3.

Comment: Did you contact the manufacturer?  It is a somewhat inexpensive charger.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Okay. So it used to handle 60W on the PD 3.0 port, but after using that port to charge a phone at 18W it seems to not go up to 60W again, correct? I second John’s comments: Contact Amazon and see what they say. Sometimes for relatively low cost items, places will just send you a free replacement.